# Visual Studio Login Program Issue

Tags: visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio and I'm having a problem with my Login program.

Im attempting to allow a user 3 attempts to login to a system before the program aborts on the 4th attempt.

The problem I am having is even when I enter the correct username/password the program still view the credentials as a bad login attempt.

If I comment out the if/Elseif code I can login without issue..but obviously without the handling attempts which I need.

I am only a couple of days into Visual Studio so simple errors would be completely unknown to me at this stage..so any suggestions or obvious errors pointed out would be most appreciated.

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Public Class Form1
    Public con As New OracleConnection
    Public ds As New DataSet

    Public Function Connect() As OracleConnection
        Dim username As String = txtUsername.Text
        Dim password As String = txtPassword.Text
        Dim connectString As String = "Data Source=XE; user id=" & username & ";" & "Password=" & password & ";"
        Dim con As New OracleConnection(connectString)
        con.Open()
        Return con
    End Function

    Public Function populateDS() As DataSet
        ds = New DataSet
        Dim sql As String
        Dim da As OracleDataAdapter
        sql = "SELECT * from Customer"
        da = New OracleDataAdapter(sql, Connect())
        da.Fill(ds, "DT_Customer")
        con.Close()
        Return ds
    End Function


    Dim Attempt As Integer = 1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        **If txtUsername.Text = "username" And txtPassword.Text = "Password"** Then
            MsgBox("Welcome")
            Customer.ShowDialog()
            Me.Hide()
            populateDS()

        ElseIf Attempt = 3 Then
            MsgBox("Maxium Attempts Reached")
            Close()

        Else
            MsgBox("Username & Password Incorrect - Attempt " & Attempt & " of 3 ")
            Attempt = Attempt + 1
            txtUsername.Text = ""
            txtPassword.Text = ""
            txtUsername.Focus()

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I have added the **If txtUsername.Text = "username" And txtPassword.Text = "Password"** where I think the problem may lie..but I could well be a million miles away at the same time!

Comment: Have you ever heard about _indenting your code_?

Comment: And well, about simple error. The word "Password" and the word "password" are not the same. Perhaps I am just assuming to much

Comment: Hi, Steve, Sorry about the formatting..newbie error and thanks for pointing it out. I didn't realize the username/password in the if/ElseIf statement would be the actual login details to the system..thanks for your help, apprecriated! :)